# Values are not sent in the soap body(not serialized)

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl, asmx

I have generated the proxy using the wsdl and i have extended the proxy class by extending the proxy class. There was changes made in the xsd of the service class and when i implemented it, the values are not passed in the request. I am using SoapHttpClientProtocol. How can I achieve this?

```
 [TraceExtension]
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://svc.test.daimler.com/2010/svc/getData", RequestNamespace="http://my.VisSvc/2010/svc", ResponseNamespace="http://dai.esi.VisSvc/2010/svc", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
    [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("response", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
```

Comment: It sounds like you are using a web reference. Web references are part of the ASMX technology. ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Simply right-click the web reference and choose "Update Web Reference".

P.S. You should be using service references instead, in which case you should use "Update Service Reference".

Comment: I have not added any service reference, just created a proxy class using wsdl and then added the same class to solution.

Comment: WSDL.EXE is part of the legacy ASMX technology. You should use "Add Service Reference" or svcutil.exe.